# What alternatives could better be used instead of "since five years ago"?

Tags: for, since

> *We have planned our summers here since five years ago³.

³ since five years ago — (1) An expression of duration is not used for a past event. If a past event is relevant to something happening in the present, then the present perfect is used. (2) It sounds very awkward to use "since" and "ago" in this prepositional phrase.  Simpler is better (e.g., for five years  or since 2015).

[source](https://www.grammar-quizzes.com/preps_for-since.html)

---

I think ***for five years***, while being grammatically sound, would not be a good alternative, because the user meant to mention the start time of the event and not the duration. Assuming that intent of the person, what better alternative would you suggest him to use instead, if any?

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what this sentence is trying to say. Are you saying that each year for the past five years you have planned out and subsequently took a summer here? Or that you starting planning five years ago for summers here that haven't happened yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, the entire sentence feels odd.  I believe your source mentions this in the footnotes, but on top of their explanation, I think it sounds awkward to use "plan" for a repetitive event.  Usually you *plan* something one time, and then (unless something changes) continue with the same *plan*.

It may be more natural to say something like:

> We've been vacationing here for five years.
>
> We've taken our vacation here for the past five years.
>
> We've been coming here (on vacation) for the past five years.
>
> We first came here (for vacation) five years ago, and we've been coming back every year since.
>
> We first planned a vacation here five years ago, and (we liked it so much) we've returned every year since.

plus all the various combinations of these expressions.

Note:  I shouldn't say that "plan" is entirely incorrect.  It's possible that this is common in British English, but someone from the UK will have to chime in on that.

Comment: I find "for the past five years" to be a great alternative.. And, right! *plan* verb is misused in the sentence.

Comment: @ZeeshanAli  The website in your link is trying to explain the difference between "for" a certain length of time, and "since" a particular moment in time -- but I think some of their examples could be better.

Answer (score 0):

@Jan is correct, but for would work also, like:

> We have planned our summers here for five years

But it could be even better with since, just change the next words:

> We have planned our summers here since (the year, i.e 2014)